# How to Setup Kafka Cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I would like to setup a multi node Kafka Cluster on Kubernetes. I have searched online for guides, but there are so many different variations. Can someone share your guide on this?

Comment: I found this link helpful https://dzone.com/articles/ultimate-guide-to-installing-kafka-docker-on-kuber

Comment: @YatinGoyal what about multi node Kafka cluster? Do I simply duplicate the containers and check the KAFKA_BROKER_ID in env?

Comment: Well it depends on your environment also. What resources do you have, do you have some specific requirements or you just want to deploy it in the simplest form? If you just want to deploy kafka you should use helm and accept answer mentioning this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Strimzi Operator](https://strimzi.io) which simplifies Kafka cluster deployment and management on top of Kubernetes. Unlike Helm charts, that only simplify deployments, the Operator approach also supports day-2 operations, which can be quite complex in case of Kafka clusters.

Simple procedure to deploy a 3-nodes test cluster:

```sh
VERSION="0.21.1"
NAMESPACE="kafka"

# create and select a new namespace
kubectl create ns $NAMESPACE
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace="$NAMESPACE"

# deploy the Strimzi operator
curl -L https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/releases/download/$VERSION/strimzi-cluster-operator-$VERSION.yaml \
    | sed "s/namespace: .*/namespace: $NAMESPACE/g" | kubectl replace --force -f -

# deploy the Kafka cluster
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/$VERSION/examples/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml
```

Comment: Hey @fvaleri, what do you mean by `day-2 operations`? how its different from deploy kafka with `helm charts`: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts

Comment: I mean that the additional Operator component embeds the specific application knowledge (Kafka in this case), which allows to automate complex operations like rolling updates with now downtime, TLS certificate management and cluster rebalancing, just to name a few.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest learning [Helm](https://helm.sh/) as it significantly simplifies the way you bring any new technology into your kubernetes cluster.

Once you briefly read about Helm you can then install Kafka cluster in one command using a [kafka helm chart](https://bitnami.com/stack/kafka/helm). What you need to do is to learn [available properties](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka/#global-parameters) and set them up according to your needs.

Comment: I have searched about the Bitnami helm chart. Seems good to me. Thanks!